# My code for downloading longitude and latitude is now returning null value for existing areas

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a code for downloading longitude and latitude coordinates from google maps, it was working before but now it's returning null value. Below is my code;

```
<?php 
        //Optaining Latitude and Longitude 
            $address = $title;
            $url = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false");
            $response = json_decode($url);
            $latitudee = "";
            $longitudee = "";
            if ($response->status == 'OK') {
                $latitudee = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $longitudee = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            }
            echo $latitudee;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Returned error message states what is the problem here:

```
Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. 
Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. 
For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account
```

After recent changes to google maps, [you will need to create an account to use google maps API](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account), this will generate an API key and you have to append it to URL that you use

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Answer (score 1):

Google now requires you to include API key for calling geocode API. Change the 'url' variable as follows-

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
```

The sensor parameter is no longer required to pass as per google developer guide
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

If you don't have an API key, you can get it here-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Also don't forget to restrict your key once you have one.

Comment: The code is not working even after I used the API Key, I tried Javascript API Key and Places API Key

Comment: You have to activate the API after you register for a new API. To activate the api go to https://console.cloud.google.com, select the right project on the top and activate 'geocoding API'. If it's still not working after you activate that API, copy paste the error message here so that I have an idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you must Formatted your address:

```
$formattedAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
```

Send request and receive json data by address:

```
$geocodeFromAddr = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddr.'&sensor=false'); 

$output = json_decode($geocodeFromAddr);
```

Get latitude and longitute from json data:

```
if ($output->status == 'OK') {
$data['latitude']  = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$data['longitude'] = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: response in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\index.php on line 138

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\index.php on line 138

Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\index.php on line 142

Comment: i missing $output var use $output instend of $response like $output->status

Comment: I did that it returned a null value

Comment: have you added : key=YOUR_API_KEY in google map api?

Comment: i tried i get api key required error:
    [error_message] => Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account :: so need to add api key

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find where the problem was, Google changed the API url to the one below;

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($add`enter code here`ress)."&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
```